# spring-aot-maven-plugin-0.11.3.pom, status: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, build

I have a Java application that compiles normally every day. Today it started to fail. No changes were made to the code.

Error message:

```
Plugin org.springframework.experimental:spring-aot-maven-plugin:0.11.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.experimental:spring-aot-maven-plugin:jar:0.11.3: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.experimental:spring-aot-maven-plugin:pom:0.11.3 from/to spring-releases (https://repo.spring.io/release): authentication failed for https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/experimental/spring-aot-maven-plugin/0.11.3/spring-aot-maven-plugin-0.11.3.pom, status: 401 Unauthorized
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTQFO.png)

What I can do to build without fail?

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of your `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with gradle plugin:

```
id 'org.springframework.experimental.aot' version '0.12.1'
```

Added from next repository:

```
maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/release' }
```

According to info from: https://spring.io/blog/2022/12/14/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-january-2023

I have updated url to:

```
maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
```

And now my build is OK.